# How can I do this MySQL Statements all in one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with stocks and its prices. Moreover, I have all Rates in this table. Now I would like to get all MArketCAP in **USD (= column MarketCap * FXRATE)** for all stocks. The original `MarketCAP` column is in local currency. So I have to multiply by the latest rates.

To get the latetest rates I did following:

Table example:

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aktien`;          

  CREATE TABLE `aktien` (          
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,          
    `dummyfield` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Stock_Short` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'US',          
    `LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `PrevClose` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `PercChange` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `DayLow` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `DayHigh` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Dividend` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `ExDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,          
    `ImportDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,          
    `TradeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,          
    `refTradeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,          
    `timed` time DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Open` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `AfterHrsChange` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',          
    `AskSize` int(17) DEFAULT '0',          
    `BidSize` int(17) DEFAULT '0',          
    `AvgDayVol` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',          
    `50DMA` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `200DMA` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `52WeekHigh` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `52WeekLow` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `52WeekRange` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `MarketCap` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `EPS` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `BV` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `EBITDA` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `P2S` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `P2B` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `PE` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `Revenue` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Mean10LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `Mean20LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `Mean50LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `Mean100LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `Mean200LastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT '0.000',          
    `NewHigh` int(1) DEFAULT '0',          
    `NewLow` int(1) DEFAULT '0',          
    `stocktype` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'stock',          
    `NormLastPrice` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `trendcode` int(1) DEFAULT '0',          
    `Todayflag` int(1) DEFAULT '0',          
    `KGVC` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `KGVN` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `ShortRatio` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `EPSC` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `EPSN` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `Target1Y` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `AdjClose` decimal(17,3) DEFAULT NULL,          
    `DMANote` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',          
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),          
    UNIQUE KEY `Stock_Short` (`Stock_Short`,`TradeDate`)          
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1594308 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;          
  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;          

  --          
  -- Dumping data for table `aktien_stack`          
  --          

  LOCK TABLES `aktien` WRITE;          
  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `aktien_stack` DISABLE KEYS */;          
  INSERT INTO `aktien` VALUES (1592307,NULL,'LUFTHANSA AG VNA 
  `O.N','LHA.DE','DE',25.110,24.290,'0.033758733',24.150,25.340,0.800,
  '2018-05-09 00:00:00','2018-05-11 20:01:06',
  '2018-05-11',NULL,NULL,24.270,NULL,4681038,1900800,948200,3320935,
   25.694,27.756,31.260,16.095,NULL,'11862591488',0.000,0.000,
  '5404000256',0.333,0.000,4.990,'35650998272',
  24.739,25.517,26.056,27.511,26.004,0,0,'stock',
  NULL,0,0,0.333,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,''), 
  (1592660,NULL,'EUR/USD','EURUSD=X','US',1.194,1.192,'0.0020306304',
  1.190,1.197,NULL,NULL,'2018-05-11 23:00:03',
  '2018-05-11',NULL,NULL,1.192,NULL,0,0,0,0,1.223,
  1.209,1.256,1.086,NULL,NULL,0.000,0.000,NULL,NULL,
  0.000,NULL,NULL,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,0,
  'cur',NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'')

  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `aktien_stack` ENABLE KEYS */;          
  UNLOCK TABLES;
```

How can I do the multiplication of all MarketCap by the FXRATE of all stocks (consider that LocalCurrencyCountry = country) in one statement?

I have done this way: ( I think it might be done with a temp table, right?)

[image]

```
    drop table if exists rr;
    create TEMPORARY TABLE rr 
    SELECT  s.Stock_Short,
                s.country,
                rate.country as LocalCurrencyCountry,
                s.PrevClose as FXRATE, TradeDate from 
                    (select *,max(id) as maxid  from aktien GROUP BY 
                TradeDate,Stock_short order by id desc) s  
                join rate on s.Stock_Short = rate.`code` where s.id = maxid 
                group by LocalCurrencyCountry order by TradeDate desc;

                SELECT aktien.MarketCap * FXRATE ,rr.fxrate, Marketcap, 
                aktien.stock_short from aktien join  rr on aktien.country = 
                rr.localcurrencyCountry group by aktien.country;
```

Comment: post tables, schema, your current query with results, and a sample of the *desired results*.  Please do not post images or screenshots.

Comment: @billynoah the table is to big to post here

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair . . . Nothing in your query or data is called "MarketCap".

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair - when I said "post tables" that means post a sample of data showing columns and table structure.  it doesn't mean post every single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at solving this, it contains 3 (!) sub-queries so its not pretty but maybe someone can optimise this.

The first sub-query is for selecting the "fx-rate" row for each country, the second one is for excluding the same "fx-rate" rows from the final result and the third one is to only include the latest market cap value

```
SELECT stock_short, marketCap * FX.rate, FX.country
FROM aktien a,
     (SELECT PrevClose as rate, a3.country 
      FROM aktien a3 JOIN rate r ON a3.stock = r.code 
      ORDER BY tradeDate desc LIMIT 1) as FX
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rate WHERE code = a.stock)
AND tradeDate = (SELECT MAX(tradeDate) FROM aktien a2 WHERE a2.stock = a.stock)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joakim, would be your solution faster than my temp table solution? Your solution looks more easiely.

Comment: I don’t know which one is best performance wise, mine has 3 sub-queries which could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do a select and a sub select. The subselect would select the key and MAX(TradeDate) grouped by the key. The outer select would join from that back to the tables on the trade date allowing you get the latest rate for each.

Generic example where the primary key is id, date. If you want specific to your tables please provide more information.

```
SELECT z.id, z.maxDate, t.rate
FROM (
    SELECT id, MAX(date) AS maxDate 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
) z
JOIN table t ON z.id=t.id AND z.maxDate=t.date
```